# how to load an image from its binary code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have created a binary file of an image using the code:

```
f1=open('file_name.png','rb')
f2=open('newfile.txt ','wb')

byte=f1.read()

f2.write(byte)
```

I have got the binary file but now I want to load that image using that binary code. Now, I want to load that image (or maybe recreate) that image by the source code itself in other file. how do I do that?

please note: I'm a newbie at python.
I have looked over the Various and found programs that I didn't understand.

this code was present there most of the time I searched. It made a bit sense to me.

I have tried the code with base64:

```
import base64 

with open("t.png", "rb") as imageFile:
    str = base64.b64encode(imageFile.read())
    print (str)
```

but this is not doing anything. not showing errors, not printing the string either.

if there is a simple way please I request you to explain by the code.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should start by reading & writing a bitmap (*.bmp) it's why easier.

Comment: don't use `str` as a variable name as that's a builtin type `str("some string")`

Comment: I have tried that too. I changed the str to string and strng, but the problem remains same.

Comment: Just did it over one of my `png` files, the string prints fine. Try `type(s)` and `len(s)` to see exactly what's going on. (`s` being your string because it really shouldn't be named `str`)

Comment: alright! somehow I got it working (don't know how), I just restarted the idle and typed the program again. it popped up a button which on clicking 2-3 times showed the string. but the actual question is how do I use the string to create the image? and thanks for the assistance to everyone once again

Comment: **please note**: that I don't want to create a file and import it in my gui I want to directly create the image in GUI.(if you could understand what I'm trying to say).

Comment: I have a code which i downloaded to explain exactly what I want. but i can't understand it. [code](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiQuID3zP7gAhWMinAKHZSaCIYQFjAAegQIBBAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fsvn.python.org%2Fprojects%2Fpython%2Ftrunk%2FDemo%2Ftkinter%2Fttk%2Froundframe.py&usg=AOvVaw3K5LhmP-3Mq1z8EjNcRNlm)